# SQL syntax for arrays within arrays

Tags: arrays, json, schema, amazon-athena

I have an issue where I am trying to extract data more efficiently from some json payloads that have arrays within arrays.

For context I am doing these queries on AWS Athena and the json payloads are stored in S3 buckets.

The table I need to use has the following Schema:

```
{
  "item1":"string",
  "item2":"string",
  "item3":"string",
  "timestamp": "string",
  "payload": [
    {
      "device_id": "string",
      "data": [
        {
          "item4": "string",
          "item5": "string",
          "item6": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I can query the data by device_id and timestamps using CROSS JOIN UNNEST as follows:

```
WITH expanded as (SELECT timestamp, payload_data
                  FROM "tablereferencedabove"
                           CROSS JOIN UNNEST(payload) as t(payload_data))
SELECT timestamp, payload_data.device_id, payload_data.data
FROM expanded
where payload_data.device_id='YYYYYYYYY' and timestamp between timestamp '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2023-01-01 01:00:00' order by timestamp desc;
```

The issue is that the result dumps all the data array into a single column/row as per below:

```
      timestamp     | device_id | data
--------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 2023-01-01 00:00:00| YYYYYYYYY | [{item4=x1, item5=x2, item6=x3},{item4=y1, item5=y2, item6=y3}]
```

**There are 2 things I would like to do:**

1- Breakdown the data array into more columns so that the result of my searching for a device_id within a timestamp window returns this:

```
      timestamp     | device_id |  item 4  |  item 5  |  item 6 
--------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------
 2023-01-01 00:00:00| YYYYYYYYY | item4=x1 | item5=x2 | item6=x3 
 2023-01-01 00:00:00| YYYYYYYYY | item4=y1 | item5=y2 | item6=y3
```

2- I'd like to know how I could do more in-depth searches within that data array e.g. search a device_id between 2 timestamps for which item 4 = "ABCD" (and the result would be returned in a similar format than above).

Thanks in advance!

I tried to use multiple CROSS JOIN UNNEST unsuccessfully.

Comment: Athena is not MySQL

Comment: Not an Athena expert, but can't you just add another CTE which UNNESTs `payload_data.data`?

Comment: I've tried but I may not have used the correct syntax. How would you suggest writing it?

Comment: FYI as per Athena documentation "UNNEST can be used only with CROSS JOIN and does not support other JOIN types (for example, LEFT JOIN UNNEST)." [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html]

Comment: As I said, not an expert (or even a user) but I would imagine the second CTE would look something like `expanded2 as (select timestamp, payload_data.device_id, items FROM expanded CROSS JOIN UNNEST(payload_data.data) AS t(items)` and then the final select would be `select timestamp, device_id, items.item4, items.item5, items.item6 from expanded2`

Comment: If you do `select typeof(payload_data.data) from ...` what is the result?

Comment: @Nick it worked, thanks!
I just made minor tweaks but it worked.

Comment: @Flamby good to hear! I suggest you post the final query as an answer so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: @nick 100%! Just testing the second part of my question and will post both answers very shortly once tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final working query syntax in AWS Athena that solved both questions raised above is:

```
WITH expanded as (SELECT timestamp, payload_data
                  FROM "tablereferencedabove"
                           CROSS JOIN UNNEST(payload) as t(payload_data)),

expanded2 as (SELECT timestamp, payload_data.device_id, item
                  FROM expanded
                            CROSS JOIN UNNEST(payload_data.data) as t(item))
SELECT timestamp, device_id, item.item4, item.item5, item.item6

FROM expanded2
where device_id='YYYYY' and item.item4='x1' and timestamp between timestamp '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2023-01-01 01:00:00';
```

The only minor issue is that for some reason I can no longer sort the result by timestamp (i.e. using "order by timestamp desc" at the end of the query) but its a small price to pay.

Comment: I wouldn't use `timestamp` as a column name given that it's also a data type. It might be causing some confusion in parsing. Perhaps in your first CTE use `SELECT timestamp AS ts...` and then use that name from there on.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Happy first rep...

Comment: @Nick yes I edited a lot of stream names for anonymity but the actual stream name is timestamp_utc in the actual query. So all referenced to timetsamp above is actually "timestamp_utc" except the last statement which is:
`try(from_iso8601_timestamp("timestamp_utc")) between timestamp '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and timestamp '2023-01-01 01:00:00' order by timestamp_utc desc;`

For clarity the above syntax works in my initial query format (with only one cross join) but doesn't work with the 2 cross join one.

Comment: It's weird that the order by doesn't work. it really shouldn't be affected by an additional cte.